# wso2esb persistence message store

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

exist in  WSO2-ESB a mechanism to save the messages in a persistent manner and handle the send retry in the event of a serious error (eg server crash) ?

Thank you

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use a Message Store plugged on a JMS Broker (a "JMS Message Store" that will use a JMS Queue) and a Message Processor that will dequeue messages from the store.

"store" mediator will be used inside a mediation to store a Message in the store

See https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Message+Stores
and https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Message+Processors

Comment: Thanks for the reply. sorry, I was not clear in my question: I would not use a broker but jms message store on the filesystem or database, but I have seen that is not present either, and I can not find information that explain how to correctly implement a custom message store
sorry for my bad English

Comment: You may wish to refer to the InMemoryStore source code in svn : http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v5/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/memory/InMemoryStore.java